# How to change icon color dynamically in Ionic-Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have a list of chats, and I like to change the color of ion-icon depending on the status of a chat(from attribute chat.status):

```
<ion-list  *ngFor = "let chat of chats">
 <ion-item>
   <ion-icon name="ellipse-outline" slot ="end"  color ="primary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>
        <h2> {{chat.username}} </h2>
      </ion-label>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The icon color should be red when chat.status is A and green when chat.status is B. How can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator to set the color in that way:

```
[color]="chat.status === 'A' ? 'danger' : 'success'"
```

I'm using Ionic's `danger` as the red color, and Ionic's `success` color as the green color but you can add your own colors if you want.

Another option could be to add a class to the `ion-icon` element and set the color using CSS (like explained in https://ionicons.com/usage):

```
<ion-icon 
  slot ="end" 
  name="ellipse-outline" 
  [class.red]="chat.status === 'A'"
  [class.green]="chat.status === 'B'"
></ion-icon>
```

And then in your scss file:

```
ion-icon.red {
  color: red; // your red color
}

ion-icon.green {
  color: green; // your green color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using `style binding` in your template:

```
<ion-icon name="ellipse-outline" slot ="end" 
[style.color]="chat.status === 'A' ? 'red' : chat.status === 'B' ? 'green' : 'black'"></ion-icon>
```

Another way is using a `directive` in your template:

```
<ion-icon name="ellipse-outline" slot ="end" [ngStyle]="colorIcon()"></ion-icon>
```

You can control the styles from your component returning an object:

```
public colorIcon(): Object {
    if (chat.status === 'A') {
        return {color: 'red'}
    } else if (chat.status === 'B') {
        return {color: 'green'}
   } else {
        return {}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use property binding "[color]" in your model passing the status as a parameter

```
<div>
  <ion-icon [color]="GetColor(status)" name="icon-outline"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

You control styles throughout your component by using conditionals and returning them:

```
GetColor(status) {
    return !status ? 'warning' : 'tertiary';
}
```

Comment: Some explanatory text of what this is achieving would improve this answer.

Comment: I wrote a little text explaining

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly provide hex color using `style binding`

```
<!-- mycolor = "#123456" -->
<ion-icon [style.color]="mycolor" name="square"></ion-icon>
```